# Source for fasting בה"ב to prevent weather-induced illness

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag

I one time heard that the reason you have בה״ב is because when the seasons change a person could get sick because of the change of seasons so we have בה״ב to daven that we shouldnt get sick has anyone ever heard of that and if yes where is the מקור

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Levush [492:1](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42961&st=&pgnum=170&hilite=) brings this reason:

> In addition to the possibility of spiritual malady, the time after the yomim tovim is predisposed to physical ailments. Both Pesach and Succos come at times of the year when the weather undergoes radical change. The sudden highs and lows in temperature can easily result in ill health. Our Sages set up these days of teshuvoh in order to help deter the possibility of illness